# ffmpeg merge 2 images into 1

Tags: ffmpeg, images, merge

how to merge 2 or multiple images into one image by ffmpeg?

I hope merge the each pixels data, e.g. average the pixel of 2 images. It is NOT concatenate or stack the images.

p.s. all images size are same

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Is using ffmpeg required? imagemagick is a very useful tool

Comment: First, I haven't right to install new SW, besides it is linux.
Moreover, it has series of tasks.  For examples, after modifying the images, the images need to do others task.  I hope use "scripts" to do all the tasks.

Comment: Well, I doubt you can get ffmpeg to do that, but I am not going to read the entirety of the ffmpeg documentation to confirm or deny that. Imagemagick *probably* can, depending on what you mean, and it runs fine on linux. If you want to achieve a goal you should use the correct tool for the job. You have not explained WHY you want to do this.

Comment: If you can use pip you could do it in python as a script

Comment: For averaging 2 images we can use [blend](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend-1) filter. Averaging more than 2 images may be possible using [deflicker](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deflicker) filter (I am not sure).

Comment: Thanks Rotem,
I succeed with use of blend=all_expr='if(eq(mod(X,2),mod(Y,2)),A,B)'